# Error: "cannot find symbol" using if + else

Tags: java

I'm learning JAVA language one week ago. I have decided to create a simple project: one login screen (JFrame) with a register button that brings you to other JFrame in order to fill several register fields.

On the registere JFrame I'm working with the register button in order to check empty fields in the register process, lauching a pop up message error if some fields have not been filled. Here you go:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE76o.jpg)

It works fine. No problem runnig it. My problema begin when I add an ELSE statement inside the previous IF. What is the ELSE function? Well, when the user fills the fields successfully, it lauchs a pop up message: "Register completed" and automatically lauchs other JFrame with a user menu. I get the error doing it. Here you can see my source code:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWlxA.jpg)

Whats the problem? Why the error appears only when I try to add ELSE statement inside my previous IF?

Comment: Post code as text. Not as links to external images. And when asking about an error message, ALWAYS post the exact and complete error message in the question, and say which line of code it refers to.

Comment: Also, post the WHOLE code of your function. I'm assuming you added one bracket too much.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear from screenshots but looks like you have one more `}` for `else` statement.